# Unity.MVC4 lazy<T> is not working in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, lazy-loading, unity-container, deferred-loading

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Home controller’s constructor is parameterized with 2 parameter(Iservice1 service1, Iservice2 service2)
Not all the code path uses any of the Service (service1, service2), only in some code path I need service1 instance/object or service2 instance/object.

I don’t want to use container.Resolve<`<Lazy<IService1>`>();

From this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) I understood that unity.mvc 4 use unity 3 which has Lazy loading support, but how to do this in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Have you measured the performance overhead of injecting an unused dependency, and have you determined that injecting both the services is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, we have hit performance badly, one of the point to improve performance is Lazy load the objects. can anyone let me know the answre for my question

Comment: what kind of initialization are you doing inside the constructor of Service1? Construction of services should be fast.

Comment: Service1 or Service2 construction is simple only, but the controller dependents on 10 or more services, and not all the code path needs all 10 services, my question is how to Lazy load the services using Bootstrap Unity or Unity.MVC 4

Comment: Steven, first of all i want to thank you for the time you spent, Service1 or Service2 construction is simple only, but the controller dependents on 10 or more services, and not all the code path needs all 10 services, my question is how to Lazy load the services using Bootstrap Unity or Unity.MVC 4

Answer (score 13):

In general, instance constructors should do nothing more than do the proper null checks and store the incoming references. This makes construction of object graphs fast and [reliable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/). Any initialization should be postponed to a later moment in time, the time the component is used for the first time.

This will in -most cases- prevent the need from delaying creation of a component for performance and if this really still is a problem, you might want to consider a container that has [better performance](https://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison).

For those spare moments that you need to delay the creation, don't use a `Lazy<T>` for this. Injecting `Lazy<T>` is a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), just as `IDisposable` is when placed on interfaces. Injecting a `Lazy<T>` leaks, because in theory, every dependency could be slow or could need to be postponed. To prevent having to make sweeping changes throughout the applications when a slower implementation of a service is introduced, we'd better make every dependency in the application a `Lazy<IDependency>` up front, because this saves us from having to make changes later on.

But that's of course silly and ugly. But even when the application is small enough that such sweeping change is affordable, why should the consumer know or care about the fact that that service needs lazy initialization? Isn't that an implementation detail? Why are we baking this lazy behavior into the contract of this service? Doing so makes our code and the tests we need to write more complicated. That's unneeded [accidental complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity).

So instead of injecting a `Lazy<IService1>`, you should simply inject an `IService1` and implement and register a proxy that implements lazy behavior. That's actually really easy to do as follows:

```cs
public class LazyService1Proxy : IService1
{
    private Lazy<IService1> service;

    public LazyService1Proxy(Lazy<IService1> service) => this.service = service;

    void IService1.Method1() => this.service.Value.Method1();

    object IService1.Method2(string foo) => this.service.Value.Method2(foo);
}
```

This proxy can be registered as follows:

```cs
container.Register<IService1>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
    new LazyService1Proxy(
        new Lazy<IService1>(
            () => c.Resolve<RealService1Impl>()))));
```

Comment: How can I write the last Register part in `Ninject`?

Answer (score -2):

Since I don't know how exactly to implement the lazy loading on DI registration level, I'm often using this way to lazy load services. I would share my approach with you.

Each service interface will inherit the IService interface which is base for all service interfaces.

```
public interface IService
{
    // I just want to be sure I'm instantiating ONLY services types.
    // This is my base interface 
}

public interface IMyService : IService
{
    void DoSomeWork();
}
```

Then, every service will implement his own interface:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        // Some action performed.
    }
}
```

My abstract BaseController class implements this logic

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public T LoadService<T>() where T : IService
    {
        return (T)System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And finally, in my controller which inherits the BaseController I would be able to do this:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    // Only parameterless constructor exists created by the compiler.

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformWork()
    {
        var testService = LoadService<IMyService>();
        testService.DoSomeWork();

        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm curious to see better implementations for lazy loading services or get to know how to implement lazy loading on types registration level using Unity or Ninject.

Comment: The `LoadService` method acts as a Sevice Locator, which is a [very bad idea](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).