# Simple Injector - "Lazy" Instantiate a singleton that has dependencies on first use

Tags: c#, singleton, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

We have a console app that does a lot of different things. A LOT of different things, and what it does depends on what we pass in as command line parameters. It was originally built this way so that it only took up one licensed spot in our build server, and I've met with a bunch of resistance when suggesting splitting it out.

This app uses Simple Injector for IoC... the problem is, we've got a bunch of singleton services that are not used for any given operation, and they load with every use... this is annoyingly slow.  I only want to load the dependencies that are actually used for any given operation.

It looks like there's a lot of documentation around the `Lazy<TService>`, but in practice it's pretty frustrating.  It seems that Lazy constructor is unaware of the container it's being used in, so it must use a parameterless constructor or a value factory that also seems unaware of the container the dependencies are in.

Is what I want to do possible with Simple Injector? I've been playing with all sorts of versions of the Lazy generic but I can't seem to get what I want.

Comment: "we've got a bunch of singleton services that are not used for any given operation, and they load with every use... this is annoyingly slow." This is something you _have_ to elaborate on, because Simple Injector is fast, and creation of classes [should be fast](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). Why is this slow?

Comment: @Steven the singleton classes themselves are slow to instantiate.  Many of them are API consumers, where it collects an authentication token or something from a remote site, or builds a cache internally.

Comment: I would like to (again) refer to [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). You should do _nothing_ of any computational relevance inside a constructor. If you need to build up a cache, do it lazily: not during construction.

Comment: @Steven you're talking about best practices, and nothing about this chimera represents best practices.  It's this frankenstein piece of code that's used _everywhere_, and we are prohibited from refactoring it out of existence.  I have to work from where I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Injector allows you to [register factory delegates](http://simpleinjector.org/howto+register-factory-delegates).

```cs
// From the link above, chapter "Lazy"
container.Register<Lazy<IMyService>>(
    () => new Lazy<IMyService>(container.GetInstance<RealService>));
```

Another possibility is to use a [decorator](https://simpleinjector.org/decorators). Simple Injector allows you to do this as well. The advantage over the first solution (where you have to call `lazyService.Value.DoSomething();`) is, that you can make this change transparent. I.e. the decorator implements the service and you can call `decoratedService.DoSomething();`

Comment: From what I read, this requires me to inject `Lazy<IMyService>` as the dependency in my singleton classes, which couples my services to SimpleInjector.  Is that not true?

Comment: `System.Lazy<T>` is a .NET class; there's nothing Simple Injector specific to `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: I... did not realize this.  I will look into it.

Comment: There are however different reasons why injecting `Lazy<T>` might be a bad idea. The docs already [state](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#lazy) "instead of polluting the API of your application with Lazy<T> dependencies, it is usually cleaner to hide the Lazy<T> behind a proxy, as shown in the following example.". The use of `Lazy<T>` is a DIP violation, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724609/264697).

Comment: Indeed.  It had a smell to me, but it's a lot less knowing it's a CLR generic.  I had just assumed that it was part of the SimpleInjector library.

Comment: Yeah, therefore I mentioned the decorator pattern as a second solution. It allows you to either lazily instantiate the service inside the decorator (Steven calls it a proxy) yourself, or to use the `Lazy<T>` wrapper for this inside the decorator.

Comment: About Oliver's update, you can inject a `Func<T>` into your decorator; they can allow delaying creation as well.