# SimpleInjector and [Export attibute]

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

in a WPF application I'm using Caliburn Micro for MVVM pattern... I want to try another IoC and want to reuse the most of the existing code...

In my application I've defined all the exportable class via attribute as

```
[Export(typeof(ITaggable))]
[Export(typeof(CorporateActionViewModel))]
[Export(typeof(IScreen))]
public class CorporateActionViewModel :...
```

How can I register them without doing manually

```
ContainerInstance.Register<ITaggable, CorporateActionViewModel>();
ContainerInstance.Register<IScreen, CorporateActionViewModel>();
ContainerInstance.Register<CorporateActionViewModel, CorporateActionViewModel>();
```

Another question is regarding the Lazy initialization... I've read [here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/430361) how to register lazy... but do I have to call the Container.Verify() or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `ExportAttribute` thoughout your complete source just to register all your types sounds like a violation of the Dependency Inversion Principle. Which is on its own questionable but it has several disadvantages for sure.

Simple Injector has no need for using attributes to find the classes you want to register. It is actually one of the [design principles](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/principles.html#vendor-lock-in)
of the Simple Injector crew.

You could easily (well easy... depending on your current design offcourse...) remove the attribute if you follow the SOLID principles for your viewmodels (and corresponding views).

If we take a typical LoB application where we have a bunch of entities in a database we could split our viewmodel/view design in these generic interfaces which your viewmodels will implement (one at a time offcourse):

```
//for a typical datagrid view of your entities with e.g. Add, Edit and Delete button
IWorkspace<TEntity>;

//for a typical edit view for one entity (including possible child entities)
IEditEntity<TEntity>;

//for choosing a specific foreign entity type from your edit view
//e.g. your editing an order and need to specify the customer
IChooseEntity<TEntity>
```

Using these we will get very specific viewmodels which are SOLID and which still could be composed to a very big complicated view for the user if you wish.

You could register these types very easily with Simple Injector using a [batch registration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-registration) like this:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
   typeof(IChooseEntityViewModel<>), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

As a bonus of this design you could wrap your viewmodels with one or more decorators which could be used to some real MVVM stuff like find your view, bind it to the viewmodel and show the view in window/page etc.
If you want to read more about decorators, in combination with simple injector you can find some nice articles [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators) (don't forget the various links).

Answer (score 2):

This query will find all types marked with `ExportAttribute`

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetExportedTypes()
{
    return from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
           from type in assembly.GetTypes()
           where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(ExportAttribute))
           select type;
}
```

And this query will find all the services published for a type using `ExportAttribute`

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetServicesFromType(Type type)
{
    return from attribute in Attribute
               .GetCustomAttributes(type, typeof(ExportAttribute))
           select ((ExportAttribute)attribute).ContractType;
}
```

These queries can be used something like this

```
var container = new Container();

foreach(var type in GetExportedTypes())
{
    foreach (var service in GetServicesFromType(type))
    {
        container.Register(service, type);
    }
}

container.Verify();
```

---

As for your question regarding `Verify()`? It is never mandatory to call `Verify` but it is always advised. The [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) are there to help.

Comment: I got the export to work but each time I try to resolve a dependency in my code with Ioc.Get<xxx> I got "IoC is not initialized" ... I use in my code a lot of IoC.Get<xyz>. In my code I've override the methods GetInstance, BuildUp, GetAllInstances according to http://www.cshandler.com/2013/03/basics-of-caliburn-micro-with-simple.html

Comment: @advapi feel free to post that problem up as another question with your code and we'll be more than happy to help ...

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly register both the lazy and the normal version of a registration, your object graph will still be fully verifiable. Take a look at this registration:

```
container.Register<ITaggable, CorporateActionViewModel>();
container.Register<Lazy<ITaggable>>(
    () => new Lazy<ITaggable>(container.GetInstance<ITaggable>));

container.Verify();
```

Verify will walk through all explicit registrations and tries to create an instance for each of the registrations. This means that it will create a `Lazy<ITaggable>` instance. Of course being able to create an `Lazy<ITaggable>` doesn't mean that the `CorporateActionViewModel` can be created, but Simple Injector will also verify the `ITaggable` registration. Those two together make sure that your complete DI configuration is verifiable.

The following configuration however will give you a false sense of security:

```
container.Register<Lazy<ITaggable>>(
    () => new Lazy<ITaggable>(container.GetInstance<CorporateActionViewModel>));

container.Verify();
```

Here the `Lazy<ITaggable>` registration uses the `GetInstance<CorporateActionViewModel>` as factory method, but `CorporateActionViewModel` is not registered explicitly. During verification, Simple Injector will create the `Lazy<ITaggable>` which will obviously succeed, but it will not automatically  call the `Lazy<T>.Value` property for you (which is deliberate, because there might be a reason why you postponed the creation of the object graph).

But please reconsider your strategy of injecting Lazy throughout your code base. This is a bad idea and bad practice. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724609/264697) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285441/264697) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

And in answer to your second question. (Did you know you could edit your original question. This keeps things understandable)

> I think I can refactor it to
>
> ```
>   ContainerInstance.RegisterSingle<ISharedModuleObject>(
>   new SharedModuleObject { DataLavorativa = DateTime.Today, 
>   DataLavorativaPrecedente = DateTime.Today });
> ```
>
> But is this ok?

I do not think so. Your calling it a factory, so `RegisterSingle()`, which registers a singleton instance is not ok.

I think your implementation should be:

```
public class SharedModuleObject : ISharedModuleObject
{
    public SharedModuleObject()
    {
        this.DataLavorativa = DateTime.Now;
        this.DataLavorativaPrecedente = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime DataLavorativaPrecedente { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataLavorativa { get; set; }
}
```

and register it like:

```
ContainerInstance.Register<ISharedModuleObject, SharedModuleObject>();
```

This will register a transient instance of the `SharedModuleObject`. So you get a new instance every time it resolved from the container.

**Edit:**

From your comment I understand you actually need a singleton. In that case your code was ok, but this seems to be a little cleaner to me:

```
ContainerInstance.RegisterSingle<ISharedModuleObject, SharedModuleObject>();
```

Comment: I was not aware I can edit a post, my fault...  I need it to be a singleton since it's an object shared between the whole code and should be only one...

Comment: If you need a singleton you could change my code to: `ContainerInstance.RegisterSingle` or use what you already had. he name factory blew me in wrong direction