# SimpleInjector and Caliburn Micro , Viewmodel auto-wired other class no

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

I'm facing some troubles with CM and SimpleInjector ... I've noticed that the viewmodel are auto-wired even if there's no Container.Registration defined for the viewmodel, meanwhile the repositories needs to be registered...

Since the repositories for me can be single instance I've defined an attribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class |
                   System.AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RepositoryAttribute :  System.Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public RepositoryAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
    }
}
```

And I get them during the CM configuration with

```
 protected override void Configure()
    {
        ContainerInstance.Register<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        ContainerInstance.RegisterSingle<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //Singleton registration
        var repositoryRegistrations =
            from type in executingAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
            where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(RepositoryAttribute))
            select new { Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), Implementation = type };

        foreach (var reg in repositoryRegistrations)
        {
            ContainerInstance.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Singleton);
        }

        ContainerInstance.Verify();

        var screens = ContainerInstance.GetInstance<SimpleViewModel>();
    }
```

The viewmodel are registered in auto, but I don't understand what type of Lifestyle is adopted (I need transient since 2 view can be opened at the same time)

Another question, for what concern the ViewModelAttribute (which is similar to the Repository one)

how can I register 2 types for a single Viewmodel?

For example

```
 [ViewModel(typeof(SimpleViewModel))]
 [ViewModel(typeof(Screen))]
public class SimpleViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly ITestRepository repository;
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

    public SimpleViewModel(ITestRepository repository, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    public void ClickMe()
    {
        var popup = IoC.Get<PopupViewModel>();

        windowManager.ShowDialog(popup);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "I've noticed that the viewmodel are auto-wired", that's because Simple Injector allows resolving concrete types, while when resolving an abstraction, Simple Injector (obviously) needs a mapping. Still, from [perspective of verification](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/howto.html#verify-the-container-s-configuration), it's good to register ALL your root types.

Comment: Can you show an example of how this attribute is applied to a class?

Answer (score 2):

In direct answer to your first question

> The viewmodel are registered in auto, but I don't understand what type of Lifestyle is adopted (I need transient since 2 view can be opened at the same time)

Auto wired types that are resolved will by default have the transient lifestyle.

And in direct answer to your second question:

> how can I register 2 types for a single Viewmodel?

You can register the same type with another abstraction just as you would register the first type.  So for example:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IBar { }

public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
}
//registrations: (transient)
container.Register<IFoo, FooBar>();
container.Register<IBar, FooBar>();
```

Now whenever you ask for `IFoo` you get `FooBar` and if you ask for `IBar` you will also get `FooBar`. This is explained in detail [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/howto.html?highlight=override#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation).

**BUT:**
Looking at your code you have some major design issues. I see at least 2 from the example.

As I mentioned in an earlier SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480301/simpleinjector-and-export-attibute/26516167#26516167) from you, SimpleInjector does not need any attributes. This will become noise in your codebase.

What is the point of the RepositoryAttribute? Sounds like you have many repositories, all based on their own interface. As I see in your code sample you have a `ITestRepository` with an implementation `TestRepository` and probably another one `IUserRepository` with an implementation `UserRepository`. I suspect both `ITestRepository` and `IUserRepository` will have pretty much the same properties and methods. So what your missing is a single open generic abstraction for all your repositories.
If you would implement this your code could look something like this:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Entities { get; }
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    TEntity GetById(Guid id);
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    // your implementation
    // NOTE: with EF you could have one open generic implementation
}

//registration:
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), 
       typeof(Repository<>), yourDesiredLifestyle);

//use like:
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> userRepository;

    public Foo(IRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

Your second design problem is that your viewmodels don't use an abstration at all. As mentioned in my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480301/simpleinjector-and-export-attibute/26516167#26516167) normally you have just a few different types of windows. I normally come round with:

- IView => used for showing data to the user
- IChooseView => used for letting the user pick some data (from a list or a simple input)
- IEditView => used for editing a complete entity

Now you can [batch register](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/advanced.html#batch-automatic-registration) all your `IView` viewmodels with a single line of code:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IView<>), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Using this abstractions you still could compose a big complicated window for the user. Especially when using Caliburn Micro. You could read more about this [here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition).

Now all your attributes are removed and are replaced with just four abstractions in contrast to an attribute in every class and an interface for every repository.

Last but maybe not least. Why would you ever want to retrieve an instance from the simpleinjector container using the base class `Screen`. Did you know that you are unable regsiter multiple implementations of type `Screen` with SimpleInjector? SimpleInjector will throw an exception when you register the same type for the second time and for some good [reasons](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/howto.html?highlight=override#override-existing-registrations)!

But besides that this is not possible to do with SimpleInjector, why would you want to retrieve a viewmodel from the container based on `Screen`. What are you expecting to receive, an array of viewmodels that inherit from `Screen`?
What I mean by pointing at this, is: Only register the types that you need for retrieval. Interfaces that are implemented by a class which you don't use or need for retrieval doesn't have to be registred with SimpleInjector.

Comment: Hello again Ric .NET, thanks for your reply... I explain you what's my problem... I've a quite huge application that has grown too fast for beign well structured....  the example I've pasted you is a simpler way of how my app is structured... I've a lot of viewmodels that has the following Export attribute for the class itself and for an interface called ITaggable that tells if the viewmodel is a part of a menu tree... in reality I don't export Screen...so I think I can just remove all the [Export(typeof(ViewModel1)] and just scann the assembly for export of type ITaggable

Comment: For what concern the Repositories it's a little bit more complicated since each Repository is related to a funcional area (for example IAdminRepository relies to all the admin's function, IReportRepository to reports and so on...) so I can't just scan for IRepository<TEntity> but I need to have some way to identify a Repository then register it as a Sigleton...

Comment: "IAdminRepository relies to all the admin's function". You should really reconsider such design, because it is quite painful to maintain. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) for a description why and how to solve this.

Comment: Steven I know it's quite a pain...I agree with you but it's not always possible to refactor code and easy thing up....